# Windows 7 split windows to quarters on click?

Tags: windows-7, display

I just experienced something weird. I was working on my laptop and was using a logitech IR mouse. I almost drop the mouse and cought it while pressing ont he mouse pads accidently. As I looked back on the screen Sublime, Firefox, and two Windows Explorer windows were displayed on my screen spliced to four equal quarters in each corner. Its a very cool feature to know how to do. But the only one I know how to do is the one you drag to the left/right and it resizes the window to half of the screen size. Any idea of to replicate this "new" instance/view of quarters?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click taskbar, select **Show windows stacked**.